# Setting up a TransformedDistribution with random parameter

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I would like to set up a transformed distribution as below:

For each draw from this transformed distribution, I would do the following:

> 1. Draw x1 from X ~ U(0,1)
> 2. Draw and output y1 from Y ~ U(0,x1)

I tried setting up transformed distribution using:

```
TransformedDistribution[x2,
  {
    x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min1, max1}], 
    x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min2, x1  }]
   }]
```

But the above uses a fixed value for the second draw from the uniform distribution.

The corresponding R code for making draws is below where `n` is the number of draws needed:

```
draw.rand <- function(n) {
    list.rand <- lapply(1:n, function(i) {
                            vec.max <- runif(1)
                            vec.rand <- runif(1, min = 0, max = vec.max)
                            vec.rand})
    unlist(list.rand)}

draw.rand(100)
```

**Edit**: I would like to evaluate the [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html), [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) of the new distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

You are after [`ParameterMixtureDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParameterMixtureDistribution.html).

```
ClearAll[dist];
dist[min2_, min1_, max1_] := ParameterMixtureDistribution[
   UniformDistribution[{min2, x1}]
   , x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min1, max1}]
   ];
```

### Your example

```
PDF[dist[0, 0, 1], x]
```

[image]

```
CDF[dist[0, 0, 1], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@PDF[dist[0, 0, 1], x]
 , {x, 0, 1.2}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , PlotRange -> {0, 5}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Another  example

```
PDF[dist[1, 2, 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@PDF[dist[1, 2, 3], x]
 , {x, 0, 5}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]